# Pandas DataFrame -add rows for missing months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, fill

Hi I have a dataframe like below

```
  Cust_ID   created_date   tran_date        Sales_Value  Quantity_Sold
0        1   2021-01-31    2021-01-31         126             12
1        1   2021-01-31    2021-03-31           5              3
2        1   2021-01-31    2021-06-30          20              5
3        2   2020-12-31    2021-02-28         200              5
4        2   2020-12-31    2021-03-31         250             25
```

I need to fill the missing months from the created date to till current month for each customer_ID. basically for each customer I should have one row for each month/year since the customer created date to the current date
so the dataframe should look like below if current month is 07/2021

```
    Cust_ID   created_date   tran_date        Sales_Value  Quantity_Sold
0        1   2021-01-31    2021-01-31         126             12
1        1   2021-01-31    2021-02-28           0              0
2        1   2021-01-31    2021-03-31           5              3
3        1   2021-01-31    2021-04-30           0              0
4        1   2021-01-31    2021-05-31           0              0
5        1   2021-01-31    2021-06-30          20              5
6        1   2021-01-31    2021-07-31           0              0
7        2   2020-12-31    2020-12-31           0              0
8        2   2020-12-31    2021-01-31           0              0
9        2   2020-12-31    2021-02-28         200              5
10       2   2020-12-31    2021-03-31         250             25
11       2   2020-12-31    2021-04-30           0              0
12       2   2020-12-31    2021-05-31           0              0
13       2   2020-12-31    2021-06-30           0              0
14       2   2020-12-31    2021-07-31           0              0
```

what's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with custom function with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) with convert `tran_date` to months periods:

```
df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_date'])
df['tran_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tran_date']).dt.to_period('m')
now = pd.to_datetime('now')
print (now)

f = lambda x: x.reindex(pd.period_range(x.name[1], now, freq='M', name='tran_date'), 
                        fill_value=0)
df = (df.set_index('tran_date')
        .groupby(['Cust_ID', 'created_date'])[['Sales_Value', 'Quantity_Sold']]
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index()
        )

df['tran_date'] = df['tran_date'].dt.to_timestamp(how='end').dt.normalize()
print (df)
    Cust_ID created_date  tran_date  Sales_Value  Quantity_Sold
0         1   2021-01-31 2021-01-31          126             12
1         1   2021-01-31 2021-02-28            0              0
2         1   2021-01-31 2021-03-31            5              3
3         1   2021-01-31 2021-04-30            0              0
4         1   2021-01-31 2021-05-31            0              0
5         1   2021-01-31 2021-06-30           20              5
6         1   2021-01-31 2021-07-31            0              0
7         2   2020-12-31 2020-12-31            0              0
8         2   2020-12-31 2021-01-31            0              0
9         2   2020-12-31 2021-02-28          200              5
10        2   2020-12-31 2021-03-31          250             25
11        2   2020-12-31 2021-04-30            0              0
12        2   2020-12-31 2021-05-31            0              0
13        2   2020-12-31 2021-06-30            0              0
14        2   2020-12-31 2021-07-31            0              0
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your solution and for the first Cust_ID, it worked as expected . but for Cust_ID 2 the sale_values and quantity_Sold were not correct. Iam still not able to figure out what' s wrong

Comment: I could not post the details of code and output  in the comment section here. So I had to post it as an answer below. Please see below answer for details.

Comment: your output looks perfect. But when I tried to use your code exactly the same , iam getting the sales and quantity values  incorrect for cust_ID 2. I am still not able to figure out what am I  doing wrong? Can you please help me out. I have posted my code and output in the bottom of this thread as an answer

Comment: @suma Unfortunately now I am on holiday, so next 10 days offline from SO. Only on phone only once, twice per day. So cannot help you.

Comment: for the prompt response. I will connect with you after you are back form holiday. In the mean while will try other options. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `*dates` to datetime dtype:

```
temp = df.astype({"created_date": np.datetime64, "tran_date":np.datetime64})
```

Get the min and max_positions of `tran_date` and replace them with values from `created_date` and `2021-07-31` respectively:

```
min_positions = temp.groupby('Cust_ID').tran_date.idxmin()

max_positions = temp.groupby('Cust_ID').tran_date.idxmax()

temp.loc[min_positions, 'tran_date'] = temp.loc[min_positions, 'created_date']

end_date = pd.to_datetime("2021/7/31")

temp.loc[max_positions, 'tran_date'] = end_date
```

from here on, we can pull it off in two ways - the first one I propose uses  Pandas only:

Group by Cust_ID, resample on `tran_date`, and then build the frequencies on a Monthly basis:

```
(temp
.set_index('tran_date')
.groupby('Cust_ID')
.resample('1M')
.asfreq()
.drop(columns='Cust_ID')
.assign(created_date = lambda df: df.created_date.ffill())
.fillna(0)
.reset_index()
.filter(df.columns)
)
 
    Cust_ID created_date  tran_date  Sales_Value  Quantity_Sold
0         1   2021-01-31 2021-01-31        126.0           12.0
1         1   2021-01-31 2021-02-28          0.0            0.0
2         1   2021-01-31 2021-03-31          5.0            3.0
3         1   2021-01-31 2021-04-30          0.0            0.0
4         1   2021-01-31 2021-05-31          0.0            0.0
5         1   2021-01-31 2021-06-30          0.0            0.0
6         1   2021-01-31 2021-07-31         20.0            5.0
7         2   2020-12-31 2020-12-31        200.0            5.0
8         2   2020-12-31 2021-01-31          0.0            0.0
9         2   2020-12-31 2021-02-28          0.0            0.0
10        2   2020-12-31 2021-03-31          0.0            0.0
11        2   2020-12-31 2021-04-30          0.0            0.0
12        2   2020-12-31 2021-05-31          0.0            0.0
13        2   2020-12-31 2021-06-30          0.0            0.0
14        2   2020-12-31 2021-07-31        250.0           25.0
```

The other option uses `complete`, with `fill_direction` from `pyjanitor`:

```
 # pip install pyjanitor
 import janitor
 import pandas as pd

 # create dictionary pairing `tran_date` with min and max_dates
  new_date_values = lambda dates: pd.date_range(start = dates.min(), 
                                                end = dates.max(), 
                                                freq='1M')
  new_date_values = {"tran_date" : new_date_values}
  
  # `completes` each group with the new dates
  (temp.complete([new_tran_date_values], 
                 by = 'Cust_ID')
   .fill_direction({"created_date" : "down"}) # wrapper for `ffill/bfill`
   .fillna(0)
   .filter(df)
   )

    Cust_ID created_date  tran_date  Sales_Value  Quantity_Sold
0         1   2021-01-31 2021-01-31        126.0           12.0
1         1   2021-01-31 2021-02-28          0.0            0.0
2         1   2021-01-31 2021-03-31          5.0            3.0
3         1   2021-01-31 2021-04-30          0.0            0.0
4         1   2021-01-31 2021-05-31          0.0            0.0
5         1   2021-01-31 2021-06-30          0.0            0.0
6         1   2021-01-31 2021-07-31         20.0            5.0
7         2   2020-12-31 2020-12-31        200.0            5.0
8         2   2020-12-31 2021-01-31          0.0            0.0
9         2   2020-12-31 2021-02-28          0.0            0.0
10        2   2020-12-31 2021-03-31          0.0            0.0
11        2   2020-12-31 2021-04-30          0.0            0.0
12        2   2020-12-31 2021-05-31          0.0            0.0
13        2   2020-12-31 2021-06-30          0.0            0.0
14        2   2020-12-31 2021-07-31        250.0           25.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In your output, the rows were created correctly for each month . but the corresponding Sales_Values and quantity_Sold are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

@jezrael Thank you for your solution. When I tried it , it worked as good for the Cust_ID  1 . but for Cust_ID 2 the sales and quantity values are incorrect for some tran_dates

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Cust_ID":
            [1,1,1,2,2],
    "created_date":
            ["2021-01-31","2021-01-31","2021-01-31","2020-12-31","2021-12-31"],
        "tran_date":
            ["2021-01-31","2021-03-31","2021-06-30","2021-02-28","2021-03-31"],
        "Sales_Value":
            [126,5,20,200,250],           
        "Quantity_Sold":
             [12,3,5,5,25] 
        
})

df

df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_date'])
df['tran_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tran_date']).dt.to_period('m')
now = pd.to_datetime('now')
print (now)

f = lambda x: x.reindex(pd.period_range(x.name[1], now, freq='M', name='tran_date'), 
                        fill_value=0)
df = (df.set_index('tran_date')
        .groupby(['Cust_ID', 'created_date'])[['Sales_Value', 'Quantity_Sold']]
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index()
        )

df['tran_date'] = df['tran_date'].dt.to_timestamp(how='end').dt.normalize()
print (df)
```

Below is how the output looks. the sales and quatity values are incorrect for the months for jan, feb and june months.
[image: Output]